# MySql Replication not updating slave - Relay log file updated

Tags: mysql, database-replication

First time working with replication so apologies if I don't understand exactly how it works.

Have two servers as masters to each other. Slave status on both show Slave_IO_Running and Slave_SQL_Running as YES. Seconds_Behind_Master show as 0.

I insert a row:

```
    insert into user (columns) values (values); //(i've already done the USE command)
```

But now on the other server, this row is not appearing in the user table. I do however see the slave's relay log file updating with the insert statement, similarly I see the master log position updating.

Not sure why I'm not seeing this new row in the slave's user table.

Comment: The simplest explanation is that you're updating the wrong instance, an instance that is not the master of the one you're monitoring. Double-check the SHOW SLAVE STATUS and make sure the host it treats as its master is really the instance you're inserting into. It's easy to make this mistake!

Comment: If you do a "show slave status \G;" make sure both the io and sql threads are running.

Comment: I do have Slave_IO_Running and Slave_SQL_Running as YES, and I double checked that the server mentioned as the master-host in SHOW SLAVE STATUS is the server I am doing the insert in

Comment: Maybe you should look at settings "binlog-do-db" and "replicate-do-db" - we had problems with not replicated data too and simply because of this problem with cross database references - see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44431961/what-is-the-difference-between-binlog-do-db-and-replicate-do-db